# path template page--path.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I am using one shared template - page.tpl.php for basic pages such as about us, contact us,etc. However, there are rental properties that share a different template, so i have created Content type - property page, and i would like to share a separate template for all pages of content type - property page. How to do it?

I tried to add path 'rentals/property1-3' and use page--rentals.tpl.php but it doesn't work

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes, thank you, the cache was cleared several times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this format for drupal to recognize the template for that content type.

```
page--machine_name.tpl.php
```

The machine name should be displayed on your YOUR_SITE_NAME.com/admin/structure/types page.

Comment: thank you, this is one of the things i also tried and tried it again after your replay, however it still renders the page.tpl.php first and than it includes the page--machine_name.tpl.php(in our case page--property_page.tpl.php) as render($page['content'])...i would like page.tpl.php for general pages and page--property_page.tpl.php for pages with content type - property_page

Comment: have you tried flushing all of the caches? Another option is to create a node template which would be similar node--property_page.tpl.php if you need to manipulate the display on the node level.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 6 :

If you want template file of each node use `page-node-[nid].tpl.php`.

If you want template file of content type use `page-content_type_name.tpl.php`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from the following Drupal article:
http://drupal.org/node/1430110

In short, by adding the following preprocessor at [..]all/themes/themeName/template.php

```
<?php
function minnehaha_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    if (isset($vars['node'])) {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. $vars['node']->type;
    }
}
```

Now, it overrides any content type with following pattern 'page--machine_name.tpl.php' where machine name is the content type name